# Trouble running mongodb in vagrant

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, vagrant

I am trying to initialize a mongodb database inside a vagrant environment running the precise64 box, but I am running into trouble starting the mongod process.

When I enter

```
mongod --port 27018 --dbpath mongoDatabase/
```

the process quits with the following response:

```
2016-05-19T00:09:28.389+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB 
starting : pid=7713 port=27018 dbpath=mongoDatabase/ 64-bit host=precise64
2016-05-19T00:09:28.393+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
2016-05-19T00:09:28.393+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
2016-05-19T00:09:28.393+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
2016-05-19T00:09:28.393+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-05-19T00:09:28.393+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-05-19T00:09:28.393+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-05-19T00:09:28.393+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1204
2016-05-19T00:09:28.393+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-05-19T00:09:28.394+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-05-19T00:09:28.394+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 27018 }, storage: { dbPath: "mongoDatabase/" } }
2016-05-19T00:09:28.427+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in mongoDatabase/ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-05-19T00:09:28.431+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-05-19T00:09:34.410+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (22) [1463616574:410690][7713:0x7f0f4ee21c80], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: journal: handle-sync: fdatasync: Invalid argument
2016-05-19T00:09:34.417+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (22) [1463616574:417296][7713:0x7f0f4ee21c80], txn-recover: Recovery failed: Invalid argument
2016-05-19T00:09:34.419+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (22) [1463616574:419466][7713:0x7f0f4ee21c80], connection: journal: handle-sync: fdatasync: Invalid argument
2016-05-19T00:09:34.420+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (0) [1463616574:420606][7713:0x7f0f4ee21c80], connection: Connection has open file handles: journal
2016-05-19T00:09:34.423+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28561
2016-05-19T00:09:34.424+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

I did see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005560/mongodb-not-working-in-vagrant-centos-box) that is related to my problem, but I really have no idea what the poster meant by his solution and "moving it out of the shared folder"

Comment: is your mongoDatabase shared between the host and the guest ?

Comment: yes, assuming you mean the location I want the database to be is inside /home/vagrant/ (which can be viewed on the host system).

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head but I remember having to run the mongo process from a different location in the file system, like up a couple of directories, in order to get it to work. Ill try and remember more, but I hope that helps to some degree